# Why do I need tabIndex if I have an anchor tag inside of another tag with Safari

Tags: css, safari

I've noticed an issue with Safari if I have this markup I can't use the tab key to tab through the links as I can in Chrome:

```
  <div><a href="#">option 1</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">option 2</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">option 3</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">option 4</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">option 5</a></div>
```

I have to do this:

```
  <div tabIndex="0"><a href="#">option 1</a></div>
  <div tabIndex="0"><a href="#">option 2</a></div>
  <div tabIndex="0">><a href="#">option 3</a></div>
  <div tabIndex="0">><a href="#">option 4</a></div>
  <div tabIndex="0">><a href="#">option 5</a></div>
```

Any particular reason.   Who is right according to the CSS spec?

Comment: Might be a stupid question but do you have tab access enabled in Safari? It's disabled by default because Apple things I guess.

Comment: @AStombaugh Not stupid at all as that's the answer.  It has nothing to do with it being inside another tag at all, but more of a Safari setting.  Well, that's annoying.

Comment: Yeah, the fact that it's not enabled by default is...puzzling. But also, Apple things.  _shrug_